# Can't connect SSLSocket to server even with the right certificates

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect using a SSLSocket using TLS to a server that should have the right certificates already. But the client keep crashing.

This is the SSL Checker on the website:

[image: server verifies our domain]

While this is the code (hostname and port are corrected):

```
val SSLSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() as SSLSocketFactory
val socket: SSLSocket = factory.createSocket(address, port) as SSLSocket
socket.startHandshake()
```

When the code arrives at the handshake it crashes with this error:

`java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Any idea why this may happen? Another HTTPS call I do to the server using TLS works perfectly, so I don't think the issue is in the server (and all the answers I have seen have that type of reply).

Comment: Since the domain you are trying to access is not known I can only guess: you are trying to reach a server which requires SNI. If you don't use SNI you get a different certificate than expected and which fails the verification. Check your domain at [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to check if your domain requires SNI or if there are other issues.

Comment: I got overall rating A. And seems that we don't use SNI since we have only one domain and one certificate right now.

Comment: Hard to tell then what's going on. If you could share the domain one could have a closer look. Note though that just because you only have one domain does not mean that you don't need SNI - it depends on the setup of the server. But if ssllabs says nothing about SNI you likely don't need one.

Comment: I don't think SNI is the problem. Maybe I have to add GoDaddy's certificate to the client? Right now I'm using the default and nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to pin the certificate in the client that opens the SSL socket connection.

For a more generic guide, see this guide about [SSL pinning on Android](https://medium.com/@richa123/ssl-pinning-on-android-8baa822e3bd5). Although that guide is for HTTPS connections, not Socket.

For the socket, I've done the following:

```
fun run() {
    val trustGodaddyCertificate = loadTrustManagers()

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sslContext.init(null, trustGodaddyCertificate, SecureRandom())

    val socket = sslContext.socketFactory.createSocket(address, port)

    // use the socket
}

private fun loadTrustManagers(): Array<out TrustManager>? {
    val certificateFactory: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    val caInput: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.server_godaddy_certificate))
    caInput.use {
        val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(caInput)

        val keyStoreType: String = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
        keyStore.load(null, null)
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate)

        val tmfAlgorithm: String = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
        val trustManagerFactory: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

        return trustManagerFactory.trustManagers
    }
}
```

In short, I've saved the .crt certificate of GoDaddy in the raw foulder of resources. I've loaded it and create a TrustManager that uses it. And I've put it in the certificate allowed by the client. That make everything work.